# What would happen if a steam gift is decline but the recipient doesn't already own the game?

Tags: steam

I'm thinking of gifting one of my friends a game that I know they don't have secretively, and if they do decline it and the gift is returned to my inventory, I'm wondering if I will be able to successfully request and receive a refund on the title, or if I would have to gift/trade it.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly refunding works, but the decision should not be affected by if whoever you were trying to gift the game to owns it or not, if they declined and you have the game in your inventory. In the end, you bought the game and you have it, so why would it matter if someone else owns it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the input, guess i'll just see what happens!

Answer (score 1):

If your friend declines the gift then it will come back to your inventory and you can ask for refund as well.